# Android Text-to-Speech: onUtteranceCompleted() not fired

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I'm working on a text to speech app, and onUtteranceCompleted never gets triggered.
Here is some of my code:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener {

        private TextToSpeech tts;
        private HashMap<String, String> hashAudio;

        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

                //defining hashAudio, its music!
                this.hashAudio = new HashMap<String, String>();
                this.hashAudio.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
                this.tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);

                this.readEnglish();
            }
        }


    public void readEnglish(){
            Log.v("MESSAGE", "reading english"); //gets shown

            this.hashAudio.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "english");
            this.tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            this.tts.speak("TEST", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, this.hashAudio);
           //gets read
        }

    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
            Log.v("MESSAGE", "Uterrance Completed");
            //never see this message
        }
```

Would anyone know why ? I've gone through a few topics in here with some solutions, but nothing worked :(. I've also read carefully the Android doc :(.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out myself, the only problem in my code was that

```
this.tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
```

was called after the Hashmap was instantiated. So the final code should look like this:

```
this.tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
this.hashAudio = new HashMap<String, String>();
this.hashAudio.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
```